# Put a bracket over a text (not in math mode)

Tags: positioning

I want to place a line or a bracket over a big text (of two or more lines length) and preferably  preventing the hyphenation of this text. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should also describe _what_ you want to achieve, not _how_ you want to achieve it. [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 4):

Probably you want to use math mode to get the stretchy bracket then flip back to text

```
 $\overbrace{\parbox[c]{0.5\textwidth}{some text here}}$
```

Comment: to remove hyphenation, put `\hyphenpenalty=15000` and `\pretolerance=10000` at the beginning of `some text`, as suggested [here at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708700/how-to-remove-hyphenpenalty-pretolerance-influence-on-section-subsection-hea)

Comment: yes or perhaps more commonly if you don't want hyphenation, just add `\raggedright` which will mean that TeX will prefer to leave the line short rather than hyphenate, unless it is really desperate.

Comment: I believe that it would look wrong with the overbrace. Maybe `\centering`? But again, this depends on the purpose of the OP, which he has not mentioned.

Comment: on \raggedright` yes it would look better done with \begin{tabular}{l}` rather than `\parbox` then the box would have the natural width of the longest line, and the brace would just span that, assuming manual line breaking is acceptable....

Comment: I will try to illustrate my question with an example: Let us suppose we have  a normal text. And another text(2 1/3 lines length) exactly next to it(no new par or new line) . How could I put a line (or bracket or  ...e.t.c) only over the second part of text and at the same protecting hyphenation?

Comment: Perhaps you need to make an image (even if you just draw in the bracket) do you want automatic line breaking within the overline?  Does `normaltext \underline{and another text}` do what you want (apart from the position of the line)

Comment: I found the ulem package. This is near what I am thinking! But there is no hyphenation of the text if someone include  \markoverwith commands in his text. Also I don't know how to make some  commands similar to \overlace or \widetidle or \widehat(in MATH MODE!!) that respect the  hyphenation rules. Please help!

Comment: @kornaros I'm totally confused, in your original question you said you wanted to prevent hyphenation, but this comment asks that hyphenation rules be respected. Can you make an image of what you want?

Comment: David, I am sorry! My English are not good! Actually my problem is  to secure(save) hyphenation!